# How to checkout maven project from svn repository

Tags: eclipse, svn, maven, m2e

I am new to Maven and Eclipse, I need to check out an existing Maven project from a SVN repository. I have installed the M2E plugin and the subversion plugin and they seem to be working properly. Here are the Installation Details -->
[image]

When I right click in the project explorer and select Import -> SVN -> Project from SVN, then select the repository location and click finish, I am prompted with 4 possibilities[image]

What is the procedure for checking out a Maven Project from this point on, or am I on the right track here?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: I usually check out projects to my eclipse via svn repository explorer (and these days, using maven via command line). But if you are still not on track after completing steps @Ashutosh jindal provided, view this url to see how the rest is done: http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2009/11/19/check-out-a-maven-project-from-svn-in-eclipse/

Answer (score 34, accepted):

tl;dr : Check out **[this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vVhNYDiqdtM)** video. The portion between 1:04 and 1:50 should answer your question (To skip to the interesting part, click on the youtube player and press `4`).

You already have the SVN connector for m2e installed. Thus it should be possible to `Import Existing Maven Project` from the SVN repository.

From the options you have listed in the above snapshot, you should be able to proceed after selecting the First or the Fourth option i.e. :

[image]

(according to Mauno V's suggestion below) To convert this imported project into a Maven project Right Click on it and do a `Configure -> Convert to a Maven Project` like so :

[image]

Comment: If I select "Check out as a project with the name specified" then I do not know how to make this a "Maven" project? ie when looking at the Project Properties I do not see the normal "Maven" interface, and I cant seem to be able to add Maven Dependencies to the Build Path

Comment: You can always convert it later to maven project by 1.) select the java project and popup the context menu 2.) select Configure>Convert to Maven Project

Comment: @CurtWalker, kindly upvote Mauno V's comment too since it was the crucial missing bit from my answer (I have updated my answer with Mauno v's suggestion)

Comment: I don't think I have enough reputation to do that on here yet heh

Answer (score 2):

If you have Pom project as a root branch, after project checkout completed, you may do it with import project as 'Existing Maven Project' and set the project as root project, and finish!

you should be able to see your module define as project in eclipse project explore, and eclipse will recognized as module project.

do right-click on Pom project, Maven -> Update Project or Alt+f5 to refresh and see the content project.